# Making pop-ups offset from default location in ArcGIS Online to avoid covering of area under consideration?

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, parcel

I am working on a property parcel and have to show the pop-ups in ArcGIS Online. But when I  click on the property the pop-ups partially cover the property. The goal is the take screenshot of property plus the pop-up.

How can I make the pop-ups offset from the property?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try using Operations Dashboard web viewer, this will show a popup docked on the left hand panel (on the web map - Create App - Operations Dashboard) [image]

Or you can use the Styler app under templates and click the dock popup button which dock the popup to the side

[image]

Comment: I did not get Styler app under template? How can I get that one. @Russ Roberts

Comment: Here is the template: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1e9d9582f9be4141a8530313ce975964  if you update the url to your orgname.maps.arcgis.com your will see the option to create an app from the template.

Comment: Could you send me the step by step I need to follow to do this operation, Please? I downloaded the template through GitHub and then how I need to update my org url?

Comment: Sure, sign into your organization, you can go to any item in your org and swap out the id= with the one in the url I pasted above. Then you can create a web app directly from that item. or from My Content Create >Using a Template Content, search for Map Styler

Comment: I think the instructions are not clear and helpful to follow. I am at beginner level and need clear step by step instruction. Actually I already have made a web map and want to dock the pop-ups on side. could you send me the screenshots like you send before?

Comment: Have you checked out the doc on how to create apps from the map viewer, or item details page etc, this can help you with the notes I provided above https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/create-map-apps.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_7E1F85B1D480416692F6A9E8EB8F1ED5  I cannot post images in comments, if you have a similar issue posted in GeoNet I can post images in replies.

Comment: I will try again and back to you next week. I will also visit GeoNet. Thanks.